# JAVA(TM) binary has stopped while converting jmx to jtl uisng ant

Tags: xslt, ant, jmeter

am getting error while generating xslt report It shows build failed with a message .jtl file does not exist. can any one help on this

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to take a look into *jmeter.log* file, normally it contains enough troubleshooting information to figure out the root cause of JMeter failure.

You can enable logging in JMeter Ant task by adding the next line to `<jmeter>` section of your *build.xml* script:

```
jmeterlogfile="${testpath}/jmeter.log">
```

It would also be a good idea to increase [JVM Heap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm) size allocated to Ant, in case of large amount of virtual users default setting might be not enough. Example setting to set it to 4 gigabytes would be:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xmx4G"/>
```

A good idea would be amending this to be around 80% of your total available physical RAM

Putting everything together:

```
<jmeter
    jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
    testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
    resultlog="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
    jmeterlogfile="${testpath}/jmeter.log">   <!-- enable logging-->     
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx4G"/>                  <!-- increase JVM heap size-->
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
    <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
</jmeter>
```

References:

- [JMeter Ant Task: Parameters](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter#parameters)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)